# After accidentally renaming /etc, how do I rename it back?

Tags: sudo, etc

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

I renamed the `/etc` folder to `apache2`. That was my greatest mistake

Now I can't rename it back because I need to use `sudo`, but when I try I get the error

```
sudo: unknown uid 1000
```

How can I fix this problem? I don't have a live system to boot from, and in recovery mode the root terminal opens but then closes saying `cannot open password database`.

Comment: Boot from an installation medium, select "Try Ubuntu", mount your root file system on `/mnt`, do the renaming, reboot.

Comment: How to boot an installation medium?

Comment: @Zanna, shift didn't show me any menu. Maybe other button can open it?

Comment: @Zanna, Recovery menu -> root opens terminal, but it says cannot open password database and closes

Comment: @Zanna, no, haven't :(

Comment: OK I've fixed it. Writing an answer now...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

An easy way to fix problems like this is often to boot from a live system, mount the root partition on `/mnt`  and then rename the file.

If you don't have a live system or a means of making one, or you don't have physical access to the system but you can reboot and get the GRUB menu, you can use the GRUB editor to get a root shell and rename the file.

Reboot or power off, switch on and, if you don't normally see the GRUB menu on boot, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get to the GRUB menu.

Move the cursor down to **Advanced Options for Ubuntu** and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, then press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot options (one time only - changes here will not be permanent, so we don't have to clean up afterwards).

You will see a screen that looks something like this<sup>1</sup>:

[image: screenshot of GRUB menu editor]

Move the cursor down to the line that starts with `linux` and then move the cursor to the end of that line, or anywhere among the kernel boot parameters there. Be sure you are on the correct line and type carefully here, as the system may fail to boot without `/etc` in place.

Add the text `init=/bin/bash` and press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

This will start the system with a Bash shell as init. You will get a root shell and the filesystem will be mounted read only.<sup>2</sup> To make the filesystem writable, enter the command

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Now you can rename `/etc` (you may want to `ls` first)

```
mv /apache2 /etc
```

Now you can reboot, or complete the boot normally from here by having the root shell replace itself with the normal init system<sup>3</sup>:

```
exec systemd
```

I tested this procedure on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Many thanks to [Kulfy](https://askubuntu.com/users/816190/kulfy) for obtaining a good quality screenshot of the GRUB editor from VirtualBox!*
<sup>2</sup> Although PATH cannot be set from the config files in `/etc` in this scenario, Bash will [automatically set one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479071/where-is-the-path-variable-set-when-i-start-a-bash-shell-with-env-i-bash).
<sup>3</sup> If `exec systemd` doesn't work for you, `exec /sbin/init` should do the trick. If not, `readlink -e /sbin/init` should give the path to whatever init program should be running, which you can then `exec` with its full path. If you can't proceed this way, simply enter `reboot`.

Comment: Very thorough including screenshot +1 :)

Comment: @Kulfy thank you so much! that's wonderful :D I can't use VB as I don't have enough RAM. Very kind of you to help improve my answer

Comment: I think I took screenshot way too big :P ;-) and thanks for the screenshot credits :)

Comment: @Racoon You're very welcome, happy you got it fixed :)

Comment: Trying to test it but not working in Ubuntu 18.04.Desktop. Followed the instructions **verbatim**. Not working. After `F10` only a few lines appear and stops at blank screen. Can you suggest something?

Comment: @Vijay blank screen or console? The shell will be text only and the prompt will have only the bash version. Perhaps removing the `quiet` and `splash` parameters from the line where you add `init=/bin/bash` will help at least make the process more informative. Can you tell me more about the environment, what you did, if that does not change anything? I am very grateful for the feedback

Comment: 1. If I click `Enter` at "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" the slection becomes the "Ubuntu, with Linux  4.15.0-42-generic"  and Pressing `e` gives a different screen than your Pic.  2. If I press `e` at "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" it give a screen like your Pic. but in both cases after adding `init=/bin/bash` at the end of the Linux  line/s it stops at blank screen. No response  to any key. I will be removing the `quiet` and `splash` and post if something happens.

Comment: @Vijay I am out, but I will look at the editor in those scenarios when possible

Comment: Removing the `quiet` and `splash` did not help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87281/discussion-between-zanna-and-vijay).

Comment: [@Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna)Fixed it by removing the "$vt_handoff " from the line. Rechecked it. Thanx for all the trouble taken by you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for investigating further @Vijay :) I will research and think about whether I should add a note about it to my answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a live USB, you should be able to boot to it and mount your existing filesystem, then rename your `/etc` from there. [Here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-usb-stick-on-linux) is a tutorial on how to create a live USB should you need it.

Once booted to the live USB (If using a Ubuntu 18.04 drive), select "Try Ubuntu without installing" and it will essentially give you a full instance of an Ubuntu installation that won't persist after shutdown. Once booted, you have a few options:

**Command-Line Way**

Open a terminal and run `lsblk`. Look for the volume that would be your original installation's drive and note which number it is (/dev/sd#)

Then, create a mountpoint for the drive with `mkdir -p /mnt/directory`, then mount the drive with `sudo mount /dev/sd# /mnt/directory`. Navigate to the directory with `cd /mnt/directory` and you should now be in your installation's root directory, but now with a working `sudo` command. run `sudo mv apache2 etc` and reboot into your hypothetically working OS.

**Graphical Way**

Open the disks utility by searching for Disks. Select the volume that looks like your installation drive and mount it. Open the file manager and select the mounted volume, right click your `/apache2` folder and rename it to `/etc`, then reboot.

Comment: "Graphical Way" doesn't work because there is no option "Rename" on Rt. click.

Comment: @Vijay That's likely because of file permissions, you will need to open the file manager as root to do it graphically. To do that, run the command `sudo nautilus` from the terminal. (Ubuntu uses "nautilus" as its file manager in the same way Windows uses "explorer".)

Comment: @AJMansfield of course it doesn't matter on a live system, but in general we should use `sudo -H nautilus` to avoid having root become the owner of config files in `$HOME`, potentially making them inaccessible by programs run as an ordinary user. You're probably aware of this, but I'm mentioning for other readers.

Answer (score 6):

1. Make Bootable USB as shown [here.](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0)
2. Boot from USB by pressing the key as shown [here.](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=58779#here)
3. Find out your file-system partition by running `gparted`. Suppose it is sdxy.
4. Run on terminal `sudo mount /dev/sdxy /mnt`
5. Run on terminal `sudo mv /mnt/apache2 /mnt/etc`
6. Check your file system in /mnt for the name change.
7. Run on terminal `sudo reboot`
8. When prompted remove the USB and press enter

Comment: @Kulfy I tried but it does not work without sudo. See [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pXvyYdxR7X/).

Comment: This is because sda2 was mounted with sudo, therefore only sudo can perform actions. But if you mount drive by nautilus (without any special permission) you can perform tasks without sudo.

Comment: Checked it `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mount /dev/sda2 /mnt  
mount: only root can do that  
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Comment: AFAIK the `mount` program is very strict and always has to be run as root; the only exception to this is when the filesystem is in `fstab` and has the `user` option. The program `udisksctl` allows normal users to mount devices, using for example `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda1` (it creates a suitable mount point in `/media/$USER/`). I have not tried using `udisksctl` from a live system, but on a live system one is always a privileged user able to run `sudo` with no password so there is no need for utilities like `udisksctl` which are otherwise so useful